# object.style.left returns nothing in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unable to access the left position of an image element. Here is the [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Y8w/1/).
The alert box is displaying nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img src="pan.jpg" id="uno" width="600" />
<style>
#uno
{
position:relative;
left:100px;
}
</style>
<script>
     alert(document.getElementById("uno").style.left);
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's style property only has access to inline styles. You'll notice it works with this: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/G9Y8w/))

```
<img src="pan.jpg" id="uno" width="600" style="left:125px;" />
```

I suggest you either only set `left` in JavaScript or use classes in CSS and check the object for the class instead of the style.

Comment: but can't I use an internal stylesheet as used above?

Comment: There is no difference really between an internal and external Stylesheet, they're just 2 different ways of specifying the same thing. I'm line styles are completely different though, they're bound to a single element instead if a selector.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate Solution**(if you do not define inline styles, little complicated though)

```
//document.styleSheets gives the list of available stylesheets for the document
//Here we have only one stylesheet hence document.stylesheets["0"] gives us the only stylesheet    
//document.stylesheets["0"].rules gives the object with defined css rules
var rules = document.styleSheets["0"].rules
//iterating over that object to find the object which has css for element ID "uno"
for(property in rules){
  if(rules.hasOwnProperty(property)){
    if(rules[property].selectorText === "#uno"){
      alert(rules[property].style.left);
    }
  }
}
```

### Updated File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<img src="pan.jpg" id="uno" width="600" />
<style>
#uno
{
position:relative;
left:100px;
}
</style>
<script>
  var rules = document.styleSheets["0"].rules
  for(property in rules){
    if(rules.hasOwnProperty(property)){
      if(rules[property].selectorText === "#uno"){
        alert(rules[property].style.left);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

rather use jquery which does all the hardlifting for us